# How many tests do I need to run?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

My hypothesis is that the wording of a particular yes-no question affects whether people will answer "Yes" or "No", such that Wording 1 is more likely to be answered "Yes" than "No", and Wording 2 is more likely to be answered "No" than "Yes".

Here are the results of a survey:

|  | **Yes** | **No** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Wording 1** | 70 | 30 |
| **Wording 2** | 20 | 80 |

What test(s) should I run to analyse these results? It seems to me that I could run a binomial test for each of the wordings to determine whether the results *for that wording* are likely to have occurred by chance. But do I need to use a further test (perhaps chi-squared) to determine whether there's a significant difference between the results for Wording 1 and the results for Wording 2? If not, I'm struggling to see how I can attribute the difference between the results to the difference between the wordings.

Comment: "It seems to me that I could run a binomial test for each of the wordings to determine whether the results for that wording are likely to have occurred by chance." You mean testing true probability for Yes 50%? I don't think this would be plausible and I doubt it is of any relevant interest (although you of course need to decide yourself what you are interested in).

Comment: Note by the way that "results have occurred by chance" is an in my view rather inappropriate interpretation of a Binomial with probability 50%. Proportions can well be 50/50 with two groups of people giving the two answers for good subjective reasons in each case, rather than "by chance".

Comment: That is a very good point.

Comment: Having read and puzzled about it a bit more, I'm wondering whether what I need are the confidence levels of a 51-100 confidence interval for counts of 70 ("Yes" for Question 1) and 80 ("No" for Question 2). I'm referring to the second part of the hypothesis: that Wording 1 is more likely to be answered "Yes" than "No", and Wording 2 is more likely to be answered "No" than "Yes".

Comment: If indeed you want to test the 50% yes/no null hypothesis (which of course may make some sense in your setup which I don't know, even if I earlier write how not to interpret it), a Binomial test should be just fine for that.

Comment: Maybe what you want is a confidence interval for the difference of the two proportions? This can be done based on a normal approximation that you should find googling for "difference in proportions".

Comment: No, it's not that. As I see it, the hypothesis consists of three separate parts: (1) the wording of the question affects whether people will answer "Yes" or "No"; (2) Wording 1 is more likely to be answered "Yes" than "No"; (3) Wording 2 is more likely to be answered "No" than "Yes". There's no comparison between Wording 1 and Wording 2 in parts 2 and 3 of the hypothesis. (You might be wondering why I'm unclear about my own hypothesis: it's my interpretation of a paragraph in a well known philosophy paper.)

Comment: Come to think of it, and with apologies for all my meandering, isn't calculating whether a yes-no question is more likely to be answered "Yes" or "No", based on a finite number of trials, the same as calculating whether a coin is biased towards heads or tails, based on a finite number of trials?

Comment: @Remster , you should probably add your three hypotheses from your comment to your original question for clarification.  That being said, a viable answer is found in the comments by ChristianHennig and the answer by C8H10N4O2 . That is, for 1) a chi-square test of independence on the table, and for 2) and 3) a binomial test on just the first row and then one on the second row.  That being said, looking at the proportions of *Yes* and *No* within each row may be a meaningful way to present the results.  ... Someone can unpack this and clean it up to present it as an answer.

Comment: @Remster Mathematically, testing for probability 0.5 is the same whether it's your questions or a coin, but that doesn't mean that it has the same meaning. We *assume* that the coin is a random device (even if it comes with a probability that is not 0.5); this is *not* the result of a data based test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A viable answer is contained in the comments and the answer by C8H10N4O2.

For hypothesis 1, a chi-square test of association (or independence) can be applied to the contingency table.

For a 2 x 2 table, a significant result can also be interpreted as suggesting that the two rows are significantly different.

In R,

```
Input =("
           Yes  No
Wording.1  70   30
Wording.2  20   80
")

Matrix = as.matrix(read.table(textConnection(Input), header=TRUE, row.names=1))
 
Matrix
 
chisq.test(Matrix)

   ### Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
   ### 
   ### X-squared = 48.505, df = 1, p-value = 3.294e-12
```

For hypotheses 2 and 3, a binominal test can be applied to each row of the table.

```
 Matrix[1,]

   ### Yes  No 
   ###  70  30 

binom.test(Matrix[1,])

   ### Exact binomial test
   ###
   ### number of successes = 70, number of trials = 100, p-value = 7.85e-05
```

Since you have dichotomous results, here of *Yes* and *No*, an intuitive way to present the results are to present or plot the proportion of *Yes* results in each row.

```
prop.table(Matrix, margin=1)

   ###            Yes  No
   ### Wording.1  0.7  0.3
   ### Wording.2  0.2  0.8
```

In addition, for a 2 x 2 table, the *phi* statistic could be used to present the effect size.  This is similar to the *r* statistic in correlation.

```
library(DescTools) 

Phi(Matrix)

   ### 0.503
```

Whether or not the differences in the proportion of *Yes* answers across rows --- or the magnitude of the *phi* statistic --- is meaningful, is up to the judgement of the analyst.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to show the outcome of testing Wording and Answer for independence. A Chi-squared test would probably work well for that. The 70/30/20/80 contingency table shown in the question will end up with a tiny p-value, so it will be safe to say the variables are not independent.

Follow that up with something like an odds ratio to show just how more likely Wording 2 is to get a "No" than Wording 1 (or in the other direction, how much more likely Wording 1 is to get a "Yes" than Wording 2).

Comment: How about the part of the hypothesis that states "Wording 1 is more likely to be answered 'Yes' than 'No'"? The chi-squared p-value would have been tiny even if the table had been 51/49/20/80.

Comment: I would still break it up into two pieces: the first piece to establish that Wording and Answer are not independent, the second piece to quantify (probably with an odds ratio--that can be in whatever direction you want, either for "Yes" or odds for "No" in this case).

Comment: But in your original reply you described the result of the second piece as "how much more likely Wording 1 is to get a 'Yes' than Wording 2", which isn't what I'm after. I'm after how much more likely Wording 1 is to get a 'Yes' than it is to get a 'No' (or something like that).

Comment: Please see my further reply to Christian Hennig above.