# Will two binomial tests be enough?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

This is a follow-up to [a question I asked a week or two ago](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590525/how-many-tests-do-i-need-to-run), which I feel didn't get to bottom of my puzzle.

I have two questions, Question 1 and Question 2, that differ by only one word. My hypothesis is that most people will answer "Yes" to Question 1 and "No" to Question 2, and that this will be an effect of the difference in wordings. I randomly assign the questions to 200 people. Here are the results:

|  | **Yes** | **No** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Question 1** | 70 | 30 |
| **Question 2** | 20 | 80 |

A binomial test for each of the questions gives a p-value of less than 0.01. Given that the Yes:No ratios for the two questions are opposite, is there any need to carry out a further test to show that the difference in responses is an effect of the difference in wordings (rather than a chance occurrence)?

Conversely, my reason for thinking that a chi-squared test wouldn't be enough on its own is that the chi-squared p-value would have been less than 0.01 even if the results had been as follows:

|  | **Yes** | **No** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Question 1** | 100 | 0 |
| **Question 2** | 49 | 51 |

But this wouldn't show that most people (i.e. in the population, not the sample) will answer "No" to Question 2.

Comment: Per the linked thread, I would *much* rather use a classical contingency table $\chi^2$ test than a binomial. To your question, if the only difference between the conditions is a single word, what else (other than chance) could any difference be due to? I don't think there is a remaining role for statistics to play here, this is experiment design.

Comment: I've added a paragraph that I hope will clarify my worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One question is, whether this is an obvious result that does not need a test at all, because everyone can see that this is not the same.

A $p$-value is really not interesting here.

My personal take would be to compute two confidence intervalls for the two questions:

```
> binom.test(70, 100)$conf.int
[1] 0.6001853 0.7875936
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
> binom.test(20, 80)$conf.int
[1] 0.1598796 0.3593635
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
```

These do not overlap and that is proof of a significant difference. However, being able to say that the chances of a yes lie between 60% and 79% in question 1 and between 16% and 36% in question 2 might at least add some worthwhile information.

If you need a $p$-value or an odds ratio as effect size measure, Chi-squared or Fisher's Exact test will provide you with that

```
> c(70, 30, 20, 80) |> matrix(nrow = 2) |> fisher.test()

    Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  matrix(c(70, 30, 20, 80), nrow = 2)
p-value = 1.05e-12
alternative hypothesis: true odds ratio is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  4.653395 18.908394
sample estimates:
odds ratio 
  9.207979
```

The odds ratio is expected to lie in between 4.6 and 18.9 with a point estimate of 9.2 and $p$ < .0001 but indeed, contrary to the approach with two confidence intervals this does not tell you, that the chances are on opposing sides of the 50:50 equilibrium.